# Is it possible for the Worker's Party of North Korea to become a minority?

Tags: parties, north-korea

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_People%27s_Assembly

> Under the 1972 Constitution, the number of seats in the Assembly was
> 655.[3] This was increased to 687 following the 1986 election.[4]
>
> In 1990, the composition of the SPA was 601 seats held by the Workers'
> Party of Korea, 51 seats held by the Korean Social Democratic Party,
> 22 seats held by the Chondoist Chongu Party and 13 seats held by
> independents.[5]

Is it possible for the Worker's Party of North Korea to become a minority? If not, what ensures that the Worker's Party will maintain most of the seats in the North Korean parliament?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally understood that the DPRK is **not** a democracy, even if it has a 'Democratic' in the name. The leadership under the WPK Secretary General KJU controls candidate selection, election, and counting.

It was common at some times for Communist parties to form [popular fronts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Front_for_the_Reunification_of_Korea) with other leftist parties to stand together against anti-communist parties. Communists always *tried* to lead if they joined such a front, and the form but not the substance was retained by various Communist regimes after they gained political control over a country.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloc_party

Answer (score 5):

In practice no, not under the current constitution. While the WPK allows other socialist parties to exist and even take part in the national assembly, several articles of the constitution (3, 11) give a specific leading role to the WPK (and its specific Juche ideology for that matter). Non-socialist parties are basically forbidden, owing e.g. to article 12 and several others.

This is to say nothing of how elections [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_North_Korea) organized and ran in NK. Only one candidate appears on each ballot.

Having said this, interestingly enough North Korea still allows the existence of the  Chondoist Chongu Party (and they even have some seats in the assembly). AFICT originally this was religious party, however its incorporation as a small minority party probably has some similarities with how the USSR controlled [orthodox] religion. "In North Korea, the state recognizes and favors Chondoism as a distinctly Korean revolutionary religion" (according to Wikipedia).

FTWT (the other party in the assembly) the KSDP [was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Social_Democratic_Party#Criticism_of_government_policy) apparently allowed some  limited form of Glasnost in the late 1980. However that modicum of opposition has disappeared in later years.

I'm not wholly familiar with [this source](https://www.nknews.org/2014/11/being-a-minor-party-in-the-north/) in terms of reliability but it provides an early history (late 1940s) of these two parties in NK. Basically their leadership, which at the time opposed the USSR was quickly purged/jailed.